# Do I handle NulPointerException in my method or fix my unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception

I have this method in my Java application:

```
@Override
public List<Client> getClients(String username) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Client>> tRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Client>>() {
    };
    HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<List<Client>> response = restTemplate.exchange(aPIEndpoint + Constants.GET_CLIENTS,
            HttpMethod.GET, request, tRef, username);
    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return response.getBody();
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

I noticed in one of my unit tests that line `if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {` causes a `NullPointerException`. I'm wondering how I should deal with this. Should I handle this exception in my getClients() method or does my test need fixed in some way?

Comment: We don't even know what your test is testing. How should we know what you need to fix? If that exception is breaking the required contract, then fix the function. We know nothing about your test, though.

Comment: that depends on your requirements, not on the opinion of SO users

Answer (score 1):

Just fixing your unit test won’t help handling real error cases.

To me, your method would definitely benefit from a try / catch as it performs an external call which you can’t predict.

Then, you could mock your API call and simulate various scenarios to make sure you handle all cases (success or failure) with unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You get NPE cause `restTemplate.exchange(..)` returns Null response.

RestTemplate can be mock object and you can return mock response.

using RestTemplate as mock. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

or use `TestRestTempate`.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html